# Golang JSON in HTML Script tag

Tags: html, json, go

I am trying to create html email content in Go using go templates.
Inside the html email content I need to store JSON data like this:

```
<script type ="application/ld+json">
   [
   { JSON Object},
   { JSON Object}
   ]
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to do this with go lang. This is what I have tried so far:

```
tr, err := template.New("tr").Parse("<html><body><script type=\"application/ld+json\">{{.}}</script></body></html>")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var doc bytes.Buffer
err = tr.Execute(&doc, template.HTML(emailModel))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

emailHtmlContent := doc.String()

fmt.Println(emailHtmlContent)
```

When I execute this, the JSON is stored in "" double quotes of a string. If I use a `<pre>` tag the double quotes are not shown but I need to store the JSON in a script tag.
Is there a way to pull this off?

Thanks alread!

Comment: Try [`template.JS`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS) instead of `template.HTML`.

Comment: Example: https://play.golang.org/p/ix-kU5pDMaE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `text/template` instead, it will not escape strings.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "text/template"
)

type Student struct {
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    emailModel, err := json.Marshal(Student{Id: "m", Name: "k"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tr, err := template.New("tr").Parse("<html><body><script type=\"application/ld+json\">{{.}}</script></body></html>")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var doc bytes.Buffer
    err = tr.Execute(&doc, string(emailModel))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    emailHtmlContent := doc.String()

    fmt.Println(emailHtmlContent)
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for